# Tables doesn't create with hibernate

Tags: scala, hibernate

Why hibernate doesn't create table? Can it be 
due to Scala, because i never get such problem with Java? (username and password are hidden)

Queue.scala

```
package model.entity
import javax.persistence._
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator
@Entity
@Table(schema = "queuebot", name = "queue")
class Queue {
  def this(id: Int) = {
    this()
    queueId = id
  }
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
  @Column(name = "queueId", unique = true)
  var queueId: Int = _
  @Column(name = "queueName")
  var queueName: String = _
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/queuebot</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>
        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <mapping class="model.entity.Queue" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Usually scala and hibernate work fine, but here are a couple of problems that can occur when using them together:
https://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=276&thread=222229